# Why did my git user.name and user.email mysteriously get deleted?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I tried checking in my code tonight in Visual Studio Code and saw this message.

[image]

I first staged my changes then hit "Commit" like I always do!

**QUESTION 1** - Why would these values be suddenly gone?

FYI - I noticed a VS Code update when I started this morning. I can't image why a VS Code update would remove these values!

**QUESTION 2** - I can configure them again with values, but it's been so long since I initially did it, do these two values need to be the same as my username/password on github.com?

Comment: This very odd thing just happened to me as well.  First commit since I updated vscode yesterday.  Global git credentials vanished.

Comment: I have the same problem (Linux, using Git only through command line): frequently, my username and email are deleted from the gitconfig file.

Comment: I am also getting this issue. I have repeatedly set `git config --global user.name` on the command line, however these values keep getting cleared out. 

I don't use vscode, but I do use atom.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and it took me a long while to solve. On my PC, Git was working fine from the command line, Visual Studio, Tortoise Git and (originally) with Visual Studio Code.

VS Code decided to give up the ability to commit giving the same reason ie. missing user.name and user.email.

**TLDR;**

Bring up a powershell window

Type:

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

Find the etc folder being used with gitconfig eg.

```
C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig
```

Edit that file and add the lines:

```
[user]
    name = my name
    email = my email address
```

**The long winded version:**

Running a Terminal in VS Code and doing:

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

Showed everything was in place, the missing values should have been picked up. This was also the same using the command line etc.

I eventually solved the problem.

Git.exe was being used from 2 different folders:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

and

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
```

But that didn't make any difference. When running each from the command line the command:

```
.\git.exe config --list --show-origin
```

in each folder showed me that the values should have been picked up, but clearly were not being done so by VS Code.

A snipped version of the output below:

```
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig fetch.prune=true
file:P://.gitconfig     http.sslverify=false
file:.git/config        core.repositoryformatversion=0
```

So I ended up editing the file in the etc folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig
```

and adding the lines:

```
[user]
    name = my name
    email = my email address
```

It worked immediately in VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that VSC has removed these values from the config file, maybe you only had it configured in a local repository, check your global configuration file to apply your username and email in all your repositories

```
git config --global -l
```

No, this data is what defines your identity in your commits, they have no relationship with the credentials of your remote repository

*source: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup*

Comment: Just ran it and see this: fatal: unable to read config file '/Users/myname/.gitconfig': No such file or directory. Not sure why I'm seeing this message. Should I just try and configure the email and username and be done with this issue?

Comment: Could I have pressed some button to remove it by accident? Just trying to understand why I'm seeing it suddenly? I've never seen this message before and I've committed 1000+ times!

Comment: did you move the git general config file? you can run this command to figure out where the global .gitconfig is located `git config --global --edit`  as long as your editor tells you what directory the file is located in

Comment: no, I didn't move anything unless I accidentally pressed something and it moved by accident. I just aded the name/email and now it works again. I don't know if I should be concerned or just move on?

Comment: I just ran git config --global --edit and all I see in the output is my name and email. Should I be concerned? Was something accidentally deleted? Should I see more info? I'm a little new to using git.

Comment: @user1186050 `new to git` !=== `I've committed 1000+ times`

Comment: I guess I meant new to all the configurations and using it outside of my 3 click usage (stage, commit, push). Outside of those 3 clicks, I've never really looked at any of the configurations.

Comment: Don't worry, the git configuration file contains a number of variables that affect the Git commands behavior, you learn more about this in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config and https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Comment: Good luck learning about how to configure git! I encourage you to learn how to use it on the command line. you'll eventually feel much more comfortable with its use and advanced features.